# Error in slicing pandas DataFrame based on Missing column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple indexes and columns
I want to slice this dataframe based on some column names, but sometimes the given column names are not in the dataframe. Pandas raises a warning to use `.reindex` instead of `.loc` But I found strange results. To clarify, let us load the dataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
d2 = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1Ufx6pvnSC6zQdTAj05ObmV027fA4-Mr3&export=download', index_col=[0,1])
d2.head(3)
```

the result is:

```
..............................................
:          :      : ind475 : ind476 : ind456 :
:..........:......:........:........:........:
: Country  : Year :        :        :        :
: Argentin : 1966 :   6.15 :   7.77 : NaN    :
:          : 1967 :   8.33 :   9.81 : NaN    :
:          : 1968 :   9.19 :   10.2 : NaN    :
:..........:......:........:........:........:
```

If we slice using existing columns, then no problem:

```
indicators_list = ['ind475', 'ind456']
idx = pd.IndexSlice
d3 = d2.loc[idx[:,:], idx[indicators_list]]
d3.dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all').shape
```

**Out>> (10006,2)**

But if we slice with one or more missing columns, an Error is raised, but it works

```
indicators_list = ['ind475', 'ind179']
d4 = d2.loc[idx[:,:], idx[indicators_list]]
d4.dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all').shape
```

**Out>> (2672, 1)**
with a red Warning

```
FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
  return self._getitem_nested_tuple(tup)
```

I tried using reindex as suggested by the warning and as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462920/pandas-keyerror-value-not-in-index), but the result is none!!

```
indicators_list = ['ind475', 'ind179']
d5 = d2.reindex(columns=[indicators_list])
d5.dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all').shape
```

**Out:>> (0, 0)**

How can I slice and get the proper size without warnings or errors?

Comment: When I run your code with `.reindex` in Python 3.5.2 it seems to work correctly. The shape of `d5.dropna(...)` is as expected `(2672, 1)`...

Comment: @Snowbunting, I run it at python 3.6, with all up-to-date libraries through anaconda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need filter columns names with `isin` (and then if necessary remove `NaN`s columns):

```
indicators_list = ['ind475', 'ind179']
print (df2.loc[:, df2.columns.isin(indicators_list)])
```

Or:

```
print (df2[df2.columns[df2.columns.isin(indicators_list)]])
```

If working with multiindex use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
print (df2.loc[:, df2.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(indicators_list)])
```

Comment: Ah, I came here with the same

Comment: You mean if the multi-index is at columns too, right? Because my example is multi-index at rows.

Comment: Yes, for multiindex in index need `df2[df2.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(indicators_list)])`