# Python Pandas MD5 Value not in index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, md5

I'm trying to modify and add some columns in an imported csv file. 
The idea is that I want 2 extra columns, one with the MD5 value of the email address, and one with the SHA256 value of the email.

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | email     | status  |
| 1  | 1@foo.com | ERROR   |
| 2  | 2@foo.com | SUCCESS |
| 3  | 3@bar.com | SUCCESS |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

I have tryed with

```
df['email_md5'] = md5_crypt.hash(df[df.email])
```

This gives me an error saying:

> KeyError: "['1@foo.com'
>   '2@foo.com'\n '3@bar.com'] not
>   in index"

I have seen in another post [Pandas KeyError: value not in index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462920/pandas-keyerror-value-not-in-index) its suggested to use `reindex`, but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for [`md5_crypt.hash`](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.md5_crypt.html), you will have to apply the hash function of the md5_crypt module to each of the emails using `pd.apply()` -

```
from passlib.hash import md5_crypt
df['email_md5'] = df['email'].apply(md5_crypt.hash)
```

**Output**

```
id  email   status  email_md5
1   1@foo.com   ERROR    11 lHP8aPeE$5T4jqc/qir9yFszVikeSM0
2   2@foo.com   SUCCESS  11 jyOWkcrw$I8iStC3up3cwLLLBwnT5S/
3   3@bar.com   SUCCESS  11 oDfnN5UH$/2N6YljJRMfDxY2gXLYCA/
```

Comment: That makes sense.. And it would be the same if I need to do SHA1 or SHA256 as a nye column?

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup yes the `pd.apply()` remains the same. The function changes thats it!